# MongoDB Connection Error with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, swig

I am currently trying a simple Hello World App using **MongoDB, Express, Swig and NodeJS**

Using latest node, and other dependencies.

Chrome 46.0 (64 bit). Mac OS X 10.9.5

Below is my app.js code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017, {'native_parser':false}));
var db = mongoclient.db('course');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('hello_mongo_express').findOne({}, function(err, doc) {

        if(err) throw err;

        res.render('hello', doc);
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
});

mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
});
```

Below is the Error I get when node app.js:

```
AMAC02PC0PHG3QP:6_hello_world_express_swig_mongodb macadmin$ node app.js
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
/Users/macadmin/Desktop/NodeJS_MongoDB/6_hello_world_express_swig_mongodb/app.js:31
    if(err) throw err;
            ^

Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/macadmin/Desktop/NodeJS_MongoDB/6_hello_world_express_swig_mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:25)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at emit (events.js:175:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/macadmin/Desktop/NodeJS_MongoDB/6_hello_world_express_swig_mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/macadmin/Desktop/NodeJS_MongoDB/6_hello_world_express_swig_mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1250:8)
```

Some places it is saying to write 127.0.0.1 instead of local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`sudo npm rebuild`

Some of the packages may not have been installed properly during the initial set up. Make sure port `27017` is not in use by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

The bson module is maybe not  correctly installed.

Try
npm install -g node-gyp

and then

npm update

Comment: Just by any chance, are you sure you Mongo server is running? If you do "sudo mongo", can you connect to your local Mongo server?

Comment: yup. Thats the first thing I did :)